# Rails Scaffold problem # undefined method `edit_pais_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a scaffold of named pais (This is a word in Portuguese of Brazil and is the same that country), i created using the follow command:

```
ruby script\generate scaffold pais name:string abreviattion:string
```

First I changed the inflections to my local idiom, like that:

```
inflect.plural /^([a-zA-z]*)s$/i, '\1ses'  #The plural of Pais is Paises
```

And when I tryied to open the page on http://localhost:3000/paises I'm receiving the follow error:

```
undefined method `edit_pais_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x387fdf4>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a small tip, rails was built to program in english. If you keep your models in spanish you'll have a hard time getting a lot of things done. You can use the :as option in the routes.rb file to change the name to whatever you want ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

`"pais".pluralize` results in `"pais"`

This is really common for people that choose to make a `News` model. Rails needs to differentiate between the singular and plural version of your model.

### routes.rb

```
map.resources :pais, :singular => :pai
```

### Now you will use

`pai_path`, `edit_pai_path`, and `new_pai_path`

---

### Alternatively

```
map.resources :pais, :as => "goats"
```

Will generate these paths for you:

```
HTTP    URL             controller  action  
GET     /goats          Pais        index    
GET     /goats/new      Pais        new      
POST    /goats          Pais        create  
GET     /goats/1        Pais        show    
GET     /goats/1/edit   Pais        edit    
PUT     /goats/1        Pais        update  
DELETE  /goats/1        Pais        destroy
```

Checkout the [Rails Routing from the Outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resources) Guide on [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) for more information

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered around with this a little bit more and I found a solution that might help you a bit better.

### Step 1

**BEFORE** you generate your scaffold, be sure to have the proper inflection in place in your `inflections.rb` file.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'pokem', 'pokemon'
end
```

### Step 2

Now you can generate your scaffold

```
[bruno ~/pokedex]$ script/generate scaffold pokem name:string
```

### Step 3

Check out your sweet new routes!

```
[bruno ~/pokedex]$ rake routes

   pokemon GET    /pokemon(.:format)                 {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"index"}
           POST   /pokemon(.:format)                 {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"create"}
 new_pokem GET    /pokemon/new(.:format)             {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"new"}
edit_pokem GET    /pokemon/:id/edit(.:format)        {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"edit"}
     pokem GET    /pokemon/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"show"}
           PUT    /pokemon/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"update"}
           DELETE /pokemon/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"pokemon", :action=>"destroy"}
```

### Note

If you generate your scaffold **before** your define your inflection, the named routes will not be updated.