# Undefined method 'delete_car_user_path' , why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My **route.rb**:

```
map.resources :car_users
```

**car_users_controller.rb**:

```
class CarUsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @car_users = CarUsers.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def delete
    redirect_to :car_users_path
  end
end
```

I created a **delete** link in `index` view:

```
...
<% @car_users.each do |car_usr| %>
    <tr>
     <td>
      link_to "DELETE IT", delete_car_user_path(car_usr.id)
     </td>
   </tr>
 ...
```

**But I got the error:**

```
undefined method `delete_car_user_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x9d17b40>
```

Why?
(I am working with **Rails v2.3.2**)

Comment: might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610335/rails-scaffold-problem-undefined-method-edit-pais-path

Answer (score 1):

Because `delete_car_user_path` isn't a route and I assume you haven't defined it anywhere. If you want a delete link use:

```
link_to "DELETE IT", car_user_path(car_usr), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure ?'
```

For future reference use `rake routes` on the command line to get a list of routes.

Comment: Oh, I thought once I define map.resources SOMETHING , the rails will automatically create the route helper like delete_SOMETHING_path ... Then, how can I create the route

Comment: I got the error "Only get and post requests are allowed." seems it complain about the method=>delete

Answer (score 0):

I do remember an instructor on Lynda.com saying that for whatever reason Rails (I'm on 4.2) does not implement the DELETE route. I feel like there has to be a better way to do this but this worked for me (using RESTful routes):

```
<%= link_to "DELETE IT", "car_users/#{car_usr.id}/delete", method: :get %>
```